# cross domain issue while creating control on the fly using jquery and ajax chat in asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, chat

Here is the scenario, 
i have developed chat application which is having Chat Client and Chat Server.
In Client, I'm creating chat window which is very similar to google email chat window which pops up from right bottom of gmail. I've used this code and converted to asp.net (http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=9)
I'm using Jquery-1.4.2.js as jquery library and I've and aspx page which contain javascript which has ajax request and response (XMLHttpRequest) and it has a code to create html control on the fly (e.g. $("body").append(''..) using jquery and css.
In Code-behind I'm creating a cookie to maintain visitor session. My code is working absolutely fine if i host Client and server on same domain!!

I've created sitechat.htm page and it has;

LiveChat.aspx has javascript which get few server side variables like userid etc and handle chat request and response.

The Issue i'm facing is that html page different domain does not generates chat pop-up window using ajax and jquery?!!
Also, I'm able to create cookie but for a very short time, it disappears suddenly. 
I'm so confused with JSONP and Iframe, I really need a direction to make this work properly

Please, let me know how to achieve the same?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use CORS or JSON-P, they're pretty straightforward. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: I've used Access-Control-Allow-Origin into web.config file. so my request is being sent to server using ajax but control i'm trying to generate is not being created using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat difficult to understand, but sounds like you're trying to access a page on a different domain via AJAX which does not allow cross-domain requests by [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control).

If you own manage this other site, set that header to allow cross-domain requests for this site.

Comment: I have access to servers but how can I achieve the same?